# How to clear TextInput without using value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, textinput

I am not using value to not render everytime user hit a key. So my program looks like this

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let debounceTimer;
    return function () {
        const context = this;
        const args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
        debounceTimer =
            setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
    }
}

const onChangeBizMsgIdrValue = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue?: string) => {
        dispatch(setBizMsgIdrValueReducer(newValue || ''));
    },
    [],
);
const optimisedOnChangeBizMsgIdrValue = debounce(onChangeBizMsgIdrValue,500);
```

and my TextInput looks like this

```
<TextField defaultValue={BizMsgIdrValueRedux} onChange={optimisedOnChangeBizMsgIdrValue} style={{width: '130px'}} />
```

so I want to add Clear button to clear all the TextFields in Filter Component since I dont have value on TextFields i can not clear without closing the modal. Yes if i close the modal and reOpen it will be cleared but i want to achive this without closing so any ideas? I can share more if you want more about the code (NOTE: The reason of using debounce and not using value is Speed otherwise when user types there is 5 sec delay on the screen).

Comment: Using controlled components is not slow, there is surely a problem somewhere else in your code if making the input controlled makes the app lag that much. Did you try to profile it?

Comment: Of course using controlled components is not the real problem but it provokes it. I am passing these values into so many components thats why controlled component makes a problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is a better solution for what you want to achieve, in short; if you want to programatically clear an input in a "react" way you would need to make that input controlled.

Presumably the reason you don't want to do that is because everytime you press a key you are waiting 500ms for the input to change, I have been in your exact same situation before and the better solution is to create a `handleChange` function and then call that with your state change and then trigger your debounce function.

Try something like this:

```
const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");

const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let debounceTimer;
    return function () {
        const context = this;
        const args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
        debounceTimer =
            setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
    }
}

const onChangeBizMsgIdrValue = React.useCallback() => {
        dispatch(setBizMsgIdrValueReducer(textValue));
    },
    [],
);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTextValue(e.target.value)
    optimisedOnChangeBizMsgIdrValue()

}

const optimisedOnChangeBizMsgIdrValue = debounce(onChangeBizMsgIdrValue,500);
```

```
<TextField value={BizMsgIdrValueRedux} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '130px'}} />
```

Comment: this is not working at all. On Frontend i can not see what i am typing in redux state no change has been occured.